# Set up testing in Android Studio with Scala plugin

Tags: android, scala, testing

I develop my Android app in Android Studio using Scala instead of Java.

Usually Android apps use JUnit for testing and as far as I can see Android Studio has a built in support for it but I could not get it to work with my Scala code.

So the question is which Scala-specific testing framework can I use in Android Studio and how do I set it up there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ScalaTest](http://www.scalatest.org/), to include **ScalaTest 2.2.6** in your `sbt` project:

Add this line to your build file:

```
    libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.6" % "test"
```

then you are good to [start](http://www.scalatest.org/quick_start).